# How can I add wpf form inside windows forms tabpage?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, tabcontrol

When clicked show button I show win form inside tabcontrol which elements of win form, but I can not add wpf form inside this tabcontrol;

Faturalar() is the win forms;

```
Fatura.Faturalar ftr = new Fatura.Faturalar();
ftr.TopLevel = false;
ftr.Visible = true;
ftr.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
ftr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(ftr);
```

it works but;

MainWindow is wpf forms;

```
MenuYonetimi.MainWindow mny = new MenuYonetimi.MainWindow();
tabControl1.TabPages[2].Controls.Add(mny);
```

it doesn't allow to do

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Top-level `Window`s cannot be contained inside other `Window`s or "form"s if you want to call it that. If you need WPF content inside a winforms app you will need to place an [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) inside the form and place your WPF UI (probably in a WPF `UserControl`). But there's no way that any form or window will contain another `Window`.

Comment: thanks I found one tutorial about it [using-wpf-in-winforms](http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) :)